# How do I get python.vim to work with vim?

Tags: python, settings, vim

I am playing around with vim and I heard that python.vim has some nifty settings for python.

Link to python.vim
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790

Q1: How do I integrate python.vim with vim? 
Q2: Because I am not familiar with vim, if I use something like python.vim will it have a crazy effect on non-python files or will the settings just apply to python files?

---

Update:

I already places the file in the appropriate directory as instructed by the link I posted. It doesn't appear to be working with vim. Do I have to source it some how from vim? From outside of vim? I feel like I have tried both and neither are working.

Also the directory the ~/.vim/syntax/ folder did not exist. I had to create it.

FYI - I'm doing this on a MAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1:

Follow the installation details in the python.vim files description

"install details
Place python.vim file in ~/.vim/syntax/ folder."

Q2:

python.vim is a filetype plugin so it will only work when you are editing .py files.

Regarding your update:

Try issuing the command:

```
:syntax on
```

This will turn on syntax highlighting.  If you want this to always be on you can add it to ~/.vimrc

In addition to this you may need to add this to your .vimrc as well:

```
filetype plugin on
```

Comment: The ":syntax on" also fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **install details**
>
> Place python.vim file in ~/.vim/syntax/ folder.

Quoted from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=790

And it only applies to .py files.

Comment: I got that far. :-) 

It doesn't appear to be working with vim. Do I have to source it some how from vim? From outside of vim? I feel like I have tried both and neither are working.